# Fail to add and delete fields in a json object

Tags: javascript, json

Usually I would do this:

```
var res = {};
res =   {   _id: 'test@tester.com',
            password: 'ABCDEF',
            phone: '123123123',
            name: 'Torben Tester',
            userLog: [ 
                { date: 1510561026, text: 'was CREATED' },
                { date: 1510593431, text: 'was UPDATED' }
            ] 
        }

res.foo = "bar";
delete res.password
delete res.userLog
```

And I would end up with:

```
{   _id: 'test@tester.com',
    phone: '123123123',
    name: 'Torben Tester',
    foo: 'bar'
}
```

But... if I get the record from MongoDB

```
usersTable.findOne (
    { _id: 'test@tester.com' }
,function (err, data) {
    res = data
}
```

Then res is still the exactly the same as before

But none of the modifications work

```
res.foo = "bar";
delete res.password
delete res.userLog
```

The do absolutely nothing. They dont return any errors and `res` remains the same before and after.

What am I missing?  Is there a chance that `res` is of a different type when it comes from mongodb?  (no its not an array, I checked that already)

when doing `console.log(res)` the structure is exactly the same in both cases.

Any ideas would be very helpful, completely stuck for hours on this one.

Just to make it more clear....  This is the actual code...

```
usersTable.findOne (
    { _id: userID }
,function (err, data) {

    show("============BEFORE================")
    show({data})
    data.agentName = agentName + "XXXX";
    delete data.password
    delete data.userLog
    show("============AFTER================")
    show({data})

    return resolve(data);
}
```

Comment: Is your `delete res.password` after the line `res = data`?

Comment: As in `function (err, data) {
    res = data; delete res.password;
}`

Comment: Yes exactly.   I just cut the code down to make it more simple

Comment: Let me make it more clear in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved it...

```
data = data.toJSON();
```

And thats all... then it worked perfectly.

So dont get fooled by console.log(data) cause it will show the EXACT same weather or not your result is an actual Json object.

Just sucks that it did not give any errors like "This is not a json object" or something similar.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the difference between objects and JSON. JSON is a string format for serializing arrays and objects. Objects are the things that have properties like `res.password`.

Comment: Barmar you are correct - I always thought that if it is type "object" then I would be ok.  But I guess not.

Comment: Just sucks that it does not trigger any errors - would have helped a lot with any kind of error here :)

Comment: There's no error for deleting a property that doesn't exist.